# Magnification: Microscopes Telescopes

Tags: optics, astronomy, telescopes, biology, microscopy

What is the difference between the way a microscope magnifies say a star and a telescope say a cell? Why is it, that the eyepiece of a telescope magnifies stronger when it is smaller and with a microscope it is the other way around?

Comment: When you say telescope do you mean a two convex lens (standard) refraction scope, likewise with the microscope? Also what do you mean be smaller? Smaller focal length? Oh and by the way magnification for a telescope and a microscope are defined differently so comparing them in this way has no real meaning

Comment: I mean shorter instead of smaller, and yes, a refracting telescope

Comment: A telescope collects as much PARALLEL light as possible, while a microscope collects as much DIVERGENT light, as it can. Both are corner cases of the need to get as much resolution and to collect as many photons as one can.

Comment: To elaborate on CuriousOne's comment; a telescope is designed to image very dim objects at an infinite distance from the objective while a microscope is designed to image very bright objects very close to the objective.